# Make a comment in script unix

Tags: postgresql, unix, scripting, psql

I want to make a comment in a script that will be run by psql with the command `\i name_script`

I have not found a way to make a comment in the script that works in most of unix SO .

Comment: "*a comment that is run by psql*"  does not make any sense to me

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html :

> While C-style block comments are passed to the server for processing and removal, SQL-standard comments are removed by psql.

Single-line SQL comments are introduced by `--`.